# SQLite3 not found in PHP5.5

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu-14.04

I feel like I MUST be missing something. By all documentation, SQLite3 is included in PHP versions above 5.3, and yet I can't seem to get it going. Below is the very simplest test I could come up with. Did Ubuntu 14.04's package of php have it removed for some reason? Am I spelling it wrong over and over? Do I fundamentally misunderstand how to copy/paste? Thanks in advance!

[image: *head desk slam*]

Comment: `phpinfo()`  or `php -i` from command line -- check its there

Comment: I suppose it must just not come in the package. php -I | grep sqlite doesn't bring anything up. I just expected there to be something online about it or notes somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: since there are 64 million ways to install php, i wouldn't make any assumptions was to what is in your particular installation

Comment: Normally I'd expect the same, but it was a straight package install from an Ubuntu LTS so I figured it 1) would be configured as it's supposed to be, and 2) it would've surprised someone else